# nested for loops, checking checkboxes check boxes values against the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an outside for loop that creates a form based on the fields of an SQL table. It works fine, placing the correct number of input elements with the relevant name, id, etc...By the way, these input elements are for choosing subjects, like math, science, etc...

In order to check and see if the boxes should be checked, I query another SQL table called subject_teachers where each teacher, given a unique id, reports relationships with different subjects. This is a many to many table, as any given teacher can teach many diverse subjects, and any subject and be taught by many teachers. In writing the inner for loop to check for checkboxes, I get the correct number of boxes checked, but now I am printing twice the amount of subjects, i.e. instead of Math, Science, English, it prints Math Math, Science Science, English English.

Here is what I've written:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $subjects_num;$i++)
{

    for ($j = 0; $j < $subjects_taught;$j++)
    {
        if ($all_subjects[$i]['subject_id'] == $this_user[$j]['subject_id'])
        {
            $checked = "checked";

        }
        else
        {
            $checked = "";

        }

        echo "<label class='checkbox-inline'><input type='checkbox' name='subject' id=".$all_subjects[$i]['subject_id']." value=".$all_subjects[$i]['subject_id']." . $checked .>".$all_subjects[$i]['subject_en_name']."</label>";


    }


}
```

If i place the echo statement outside the inner first loop, i get the correct number of checkboxes, but an incorrect (less) boxes checked. For the example I'm using, the first two boxes should be checked.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to add a break in the if condition of the inner loop

```
if ($all_subjects[$i]['subject_id'] == $this_user[$j]['subject_id'])
   {
       $checked = "checked";
       break;
   }
```